# Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380... while using docker on Ubuntu WSL 2

Tags: linux, docker, mariadb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am following an already written guideline on running docker and Mariadb on VM. but I am using wsl ubuntu on windows.
`(sudo) apt update`
`(sudo) apt upgrade`

```
* Docker
```

`(sudo) apt-get install docker.io`

- Portainer

1. `(sudo) docker volume create portainer_data`
2. `(sudo) docker run --name portainer -d -p 9000:9000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer --log-opt max-size=50m --log-opt max-file=5 -d --privileged -p 9000:9000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /path/on/host/data:/data portainer/portainer`

- MariaDB

1. `(sudo) mkdir /mnt/raid/data/mariadb`
2. `(sudo) mkdir /mnt/raid/data/mariadb/storage`
3. `(sudo) touch /mnt/raid/data/mariadb/config.cnf`
4. `(sudo) nano /mnt/raid/data/mariadb/config.cnf`

but I get an error whenever I run  `docker run --log-opt max-size=50m --log-opt max-file=5 --name mariadb -v /mnt/raid/data/mariadb/storage:/var/lib/mysql -v /mnt/raid/data/mariadb/config.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin -d mariadb/server:latest`

This is the error:

`Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed:  container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545:  container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:75: mounting "/run/desktop/mnt/host/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu/e18d5bf9d7f9627840069cbdafadd22ec458ffe154082d3c685ed8b1a4f15eb2"  to rootfs at "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" caused: mount through procfd: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type`

I guess it might be an error with the mounting because I cannot locate the locations of the created path or the folder in the system.

Comment: AFAIK the WSL should be using Docker for Windows rather than docker (for linux) running in a WSL environment.